# Using quantile function in data.table

Tags: r, statistics, data.table

I try to calculate the mean of some values in a data.table. The mean should be calculated without outliers, which means i have to filter the data first.
In order to define outliers in my data i use the "default boxplot" approach.

This approach works perfectly:

```
test <- template[Month==1] # create small subset with data from January
qnt <- quantile(test$x,c(.25,.75)
H <- 1.5 * IQR(test$x)
test[x < (qnt[2]+H) & x > (qnt[1]-H),mean(add)]
[1] -6113.136
```

I can also make the calculations within the datatable:

```
test <- template[Month==1] # create small subset with data from January
test[x < (quantile(x,0.75)+1.5*IQR(x)) & x > (quantile(x,0.25)-1.5*IQR(x)),mean(x)]
[1] -6113.136
```

Since i need the mean not only for January but for all months i tried this:

```
template[x < (quantile(x,0.75)+1.5*IQR(x)) & x > (quantile(x,0.25)-1.5*IQR(x)),mean(x),by=Month]
 1:     1 -5601.3050 <<< not the same value than before
 2:     2  1187.3186
 ...
```

The January of the last approach is different than the January before. As far as i could figure out the quantile() method is the issue. I guess it doesn't include the 'by=Month' grouping of the data.table.

Is there anything wrong about my general approach?
Is there a way to make those calculations without splitting the 'template' data.table in 12 smaller tables first?

Many thanks for your help!

**Update:**

```
template[,.SD[x < (quantile(x,0.75)+1.5*IQR(x)) & x > (quantile(x,0.25)-1.5*IQR(x)),mean(x)],by=Month]
1:     1 -6113.1362
2:     2  1529.4808
```

Thanks @Frank and @Roland for the super fast support!

Comment: Yeah, the `i` arg to `DT[i,j,by]` does not use the `by` grouping. You could do `DT[, .SD[your_conditions, mean(x)] , by=Month]` though, I think. Also, I've never used it, but you might want to look at `help("%between%")`

Comment: If you want to subset the `.SD` data.tables created by `by`, you need to do so. Your expression in i is applied prior to  `by` (as it should, because sometimes that's what you'd want to do).

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the trim argument to mean or try a winsorized mean? This also raises the question whether you should instead be using the median if your fences are determined by the IQR's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template[,.SD[x < (quantile(x,0.75)+1.5*IQR(x)) & x > (quantile(x,0.25)-1.5*IQR(x)),mean(x)],by=Month]
```

as Frank and Roland stated out i needed to change my expression because `i` arg in `DT[i,j,by]` does not use the by grouping. Using `.SD[]` is the solution